# Matching exactly 10 digits in JavaScript and making Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex

I want to create this function:

- If ID is 10 digits it should make ajax call to file number 1
- If ID is 18 digits it should make ajax call to another file

Here is the code:

```
function get_invoice_info(expressid,expressno,div_id)
{
    document.getElementById("retData")
       .innerHTML="<center>Please wait fetching tracking details for you...</center>";

    var expressno = '{$order.invoice_no}';
    var matches = expressno.match(/^\d{12}$/);

    Ajax.call('plugins/track/tracking.php?CN='+ expressno,
        'showtest=showtest', 
        function(data){
            document.getElementById("retData").innerHTML=data;
        }, 
        'GET', 
        'TEXT'
    );

    } else {
      Ajax.call('plugins/track/tracking.php?CN='+ expressno,
         'showtest=showtest', 
         function(data) {
             document.getElementById("retData").innerHTML=data;
         }, 
         'GET', 
         'TEXT'
      );    
   }
```

This code is working exactly as i wanted it to be

```
function get_invoice_info(expressid,expressno,div_id)
{
    var waitMsg = "Please wait fetching tracking details for you...";
    document.getElementById("retData").innerHTML= waitMsg;
    var expressno = '{$order.invoice_no}';
    if(expressno.length === 12) {
    filePath='tracking';
    } else if(expressno.length === 18) {   
    filePath='track';
    } else {
    //Not in range, so exit
    return;
  }
    Ajax.call('plugins/track/'+filePath+'.php?CN='+ expressno, 'showtest=showtest', function(data){document.getElementById("retData").innerHTML=data;}, 'GET', 'TEXT');

}
```

Comment: `<center>` tag is long time deprecated, makes me wander where you got that code from...

Comment: I just formatted your code and you have an `else` without an `if` ...

Comment: If I asked your question... I would explain what's file1 and file2, or at least use it in code, but that's me...

Comment: the question is unclear, where is the id & from where you are getting it?

Comment: I just want to make if else statement rest is all working fine

Comment: @brk the id come from php `{$order.invoice_no}` would be converted into an id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I missing something, seems like you can just check length (or does it need to only be numeric, in which case you can add another if statement to the beginning that checks for non numeric characters).

```
function get_invoice_info(expressid,expressno,div_id) {
  var waitMsg = "Please wait fetching tracking details for you...";
  var expressno = '{$order.invoice_no}';
  var filePath = null;

  document.getElementById("retData").innerHTML= waitMsg;

  if(expressno.length === 10) {
    filePath='file1';
  } else if(expressno.length === 16) {   
    filePath='file2';
  } else {
    //Not in range, so exit
    return;
  }
  var onSuccess = function(data){
      document.getElementById("retData").innerHTML=data;
  };
  Ajax.call('plugins/track/'+filePath+'.php?CN='+ expressno,
     'showtest=showtest', 
     onSuccess, 
     'GET', 
     'TEXT'
);
```

Comment: Made some changes in your code its working now i have updated main question Thanks